# How to make a new Column based on conditions

Tags: r, statistics

I have 2 columns in my table: ROM and Treatment

ROM is filled with values between -20 and 20 and Treatment has 0 or 1.

I need to find a way to get all the ROM values that are in the control group (so Treatment 0) together, and all the ROM values that are in the treatment group together (so treatment1).

Could someone please tell me how I can do this so I can compare the 2 new columns?

In SQL it would be something like `SELECT ROM WHERE TREATMENT = 0`

Comment: If this kind of question is hard for you, I would recommend you read some introductory texts on R, e.g. the manuals on CRAN. This is not meant to be a mean comment, but these kind of questions are answered by a good tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered many times already, but here we go. Simple subset:

```
df[df$Treatment == 1,]
```

Get the average `ROM` per unique level in `Treatment`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(Treatment), summarise, mn = mean(ROM))
```